# Spring Boot secrets from AWS Secrets Manager in kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager, kubernetes-secrets

I've been checking that the recommended way of accessing secrets from pods in a Kubernetes environment is through the use of Kubernetes native secrets and mounting them into the pods as volumes or setting environment variables for the pod.

The recommened way from AWS is use their [secrets-store-csi-provider-aws](https://github.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws), this will mount the secrets from AWS Secrets manager as a volume, then I could use [spring-cloud-kubernetes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#secrets-propertysource) to read the secret and set it as Spring Boot configuration.

Spring Boot also offers an [integration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_secrets_manager) to easily get secrets from AWS Secrets Manager, this option is simpler than installing a k8s controller.

I'm wondering if I'm loosing any benefits from using the native Spring Boot integration over going with the [secrets-store-csi-provider-aws](https://github.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws), what are the use cases of one option over another?

Any clarification would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Six of one, half dozen of the other I say. With the Spring Boot integration you will need an access key secret key to call AWS Secrets Manager APIs (these permissions can be scoped to a specific secret) or or you can assign the Pod an IAM role with IRSA. The CSI driver has to be granted full access to AWS Secrets Manager in order to fetch and mount secrets, however, it can also be configured to re-mount secrets when they are rotated AND you can use it to synchronize secrets from AWS Secrets Manger to Kubernetes.